# Is it possible to have multiple rolebindings on the same service account in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Is it possible to have multiple rolebindings on the same service account in k8s?

Comment: Yes. You can define multiple rolebindings that all reference the same service account subject. Permissions are additive, so the service account will have all permissions in all roles it is bound to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, you can have multiple role bindings for a specific service account.
say, you want to grant read only permissions to SA at cluster level, and read and write permissions at namespace level. in this case you will be creating one role binding at namespace level and another at cluster level